# Multi-View Application Problem

Tags: iphone, ios4

I want to make multi view application. My goal is when program launch to load first view controller and then when press the button to load new tab bar controller and dismiss first controller. I try myself and I do firt step, but when tab bar controller is loaded it's appear only small tab without any tabs and old controller doesn't disappear.

This is what I've done:

**SwitchAppelegate**

```
-- Header file --
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class SwitchClass;

@interface SwitchAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    SwitchClass *switchClass;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet SwitchClass *switchClass;

@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel;
@property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *persistentStoreCoordinator;

- (void)saveContext;
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory;

@end

-- Implementation file --
#import "SwitchAppDelegate.h"

@implementation SwitchAppDelegate


@synthesize window=_window;

@synthesize managedObjectContext=__managedObjectContext;

@synthesize managedObjectModel=__managedObjectModel;

@synthesize persistentStoreCoordinator=__persistentStoreCoordinator;

@synthesize switchClass;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self.window addSubview:[switchClass view]];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

**SwitchClass**

```
-- Header file --

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class BlueClass;

@interface SwitchClass : UIViewController {
    BlueClass *blueClass;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet BlueClass *blueClass;

@end

-- Implementation file --

#import "SwitchClass.h"
#import "BlueClass.h"

@implementation SwitchClass

@synthesize blueClass;

-(void) viewDidLoad {
    BlueClass *blue = [[BlueClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"BlueClass" bundle:nil];
    self.blueClass = blue;

    [self.view insertSubview:blue.view atIndex:0];
    [blue release];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [blueClass release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

**BlueClass**

```
-- Header file --

@class RedClass;

@interface BlueClass : UIViewController {
    RedClass *redClass;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet RedClass *redClass;

-(IBAction) switch: (id) sender;

@end

-- Implementation file --

#import "BlueClass.h"
#import "RedClass.h"

@implementation BlueClass

@synthesize redClass;

-(IBAction) switch: (id) sender {
    RedClass *blue = [[RedClass alloc] initWithNibName:@"RedClass" bundle:nil];
    self.redClass = blue;
//    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.view addSubview:blue.view];
    [blue release];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [redClass release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

**RedClass**

```
-- Header file --

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RedClass : UITabBarController {

}

@end

-- Implementation file --

#import "RedClass.h"

@implementation RedClass


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{   
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is that in the appDelegate you are adding the view of SwitchClass. But SwitchClass is a UIViewController class and not UIView. so instead of that you should add your SwitchClass as a rootController like this:

```
self.window.rootViewController = self.switchClass;
```

If I were you I would just use a tab bar template provided by XCode. It will do it for you automatically.